# python Script for Grasshopper not accepting additional files

Tags: python, grasshopper

I have the following python script, it imports .json files and plots them through rhino/grasshopper. When I link file paths too it it seems to work fine until I hit 17 files and once I try to input the 18th and onward I get the following message "1. Solution exception:list.index(item): item not in list"

Anyone have any ideas? I am really lost when it comes to coding etc...
Thanks!

> ```
> import json
>
>
> if FilePath:
>
>
>     # JSON file to read
>     file = open(FilePath)
>
>     # Load the data
>     data = json.load(file)
>
>
>     import pprint
>     pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
>
>     a=[];
>     b=[];
>
>     L = list(data[0]['segments'])
>
> y = len(L)
>
> print y
>
> pp.pprint(L)
>
>
>
>
> for x in range (0,1):
>     M = list(L[x]['activities'])
>     q = len(M)
>     print q
>     for w in range (0, q):
>         N = list(M[w]['trackPoints'])
>         r = len(N)
>         print r
>         for final in range (0,r):
>             c = N[final]['lat']
>             d = N[final]['lon']
>
>             a.append(c)
>             b.append(d)
>
> for x in range (2,2):
>     M = list(L[x]['activities'])
>     q = len(M)
>     print q
>     for w in range (0, q):
>         N = list(M[w]['trackPoints'])
>         r = len(N)
>         print r
>         for final in range (0,r):
>             c = N[final]['lat']
>             d = N[final]['lon']
>
>             a.append(c)
>             b.append(d)
>
> for x in range (3,5):
>     M = list(L[x]['activities'])
>     q = len(M)
>     print q
>     for w in range (0, q):
>         N = list(M[w]['trackPoints'])
>         r = len(N)
>         print r
>         for final in range (0,r):
>             c = N[final]['lat']
>             d = N[final]['lon']
>
>             a.append(c)
>             b.append(d)
>
> for x in range (6,7):
>     M = list(L[x]['activities'])
>     q = len(M)
>     print q
>     for w in range (0, q):
>         N = list(M[w]['trackPoints'])
>         r = len(N)
>         print r
>         for final in range (0,r):
>             c = N[final]['lat']
>             d = N[final]['lon']
>
>             a.append(c)
>             b.append(d)
>
>     for x in range (8,11):
>         M = list(L[x]['activities'])
>         q = len(M)
>         print q
>         for w in range (0, q):
>             N = list(M[w]['trackPoints'])
>             r = len(N)
>             print r
>             for final in range (0,r):
>                 c = N[final]['lat']
>                 d = N[final]['lon']
>
>                 a.append(c)
>                 b.append(d)
>
>     for x in range (12,12):
>         M = list(L[x]['activities'])
>         q = len(M)
>         print q
>         for w in range (0, q):
>             N = list(M[w]['trackPoints'])
>             r = len(N)
>             print r
>             for final in range (0,r):
>                 c = N[final]['lat']
>                 d = N[final]['lon']
>
>                 a.append(c)
>                 b.append(d)
> ```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to contain a call to the `list.index(item)` function, so this error is happening in some other code.  The error means that `item` was not found in `list`.  You should post the full traceback of the exception.  Without this, there is not enough information to help.

Comment: If it is happening somewhere else, maybe link a minimal version of the full file, and 20 or so sample json files.